# Is there a way to avoid the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm building an app with Google Sign Up button. Google suggested for me to use Google+ instead, which I did.

I'm asking for users profiles and email address in two different scopes (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`). However, I noticed that the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` is added automatically in the token request response.

Is there a way to remove it? I'd like only to ask users for the two I've mentioned in order not to have additional permission requests in the dialog box, and this one also causes a confirmation popup for access to users' circles (which I don't need). I've Googled about it a lot, but couldn't find anything related to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Previously you could not remove the `plus.login` scope from the Google+ Sign-In button, as profile information for users who had not upgraded to Google+ was not available from the Google+ APIs. [Now you can choose whether you want to require a Google+ upgraded user](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html) and get access to the users' circles and the ability to write app activites, or just request basic profile information.

1. For full Google+ Sign-In include `email` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scopes.
2. For basic profile information include `email` and `profile` scopes. Note that these are just the bare strings `profile` and `email` - they are not in URL form.

The user's email address and profile information will be available from the [Google+ profile endpoint](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). You can always allow users to upgrade to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` later using [incremental auth](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#incremental) so they can take advantage of access to circles users and writing app activities.

Answer (score 2):

To use the Google+ Sign-In button you must request https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

plus.login includes a basic set of permissions that a generally useful including a request to read a users circles.  Users can easily choose not to grant access to their circles for your app by simply selecting the 'Only you' option that is presented prominently on the consent dialog.  However, it is not possible to reduce that set of permissions included in plus.login.

Comment: Yes, but even with 'Only you' you get that annoying second popup... I'm trying to get rid of that.

Comment: Shomz: That second popup only occurs for users with private circles, which should be a small percentage of users as most don't seem to know that capability exists.